# field error in odoo (openerp)?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I am a beginner in develop module odoo, so when running my module odoo,I have this result :

Module Architecture is:
    *init.py* (where I import module.py)
    *openerp.py* (dependencies: Base)
    _module.py (where I've got the main code and everything works fine)
    templates.xml (Main view going with the main code, no problem)

```
    2015-05-26 08:13:05,515 6260 ERROR odoodb1    openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_ui_view: Field `titre` does not exist

Error context:
View `document.form`
[view_id: 873, xml_id: document_binov.document_form, model: document_binov.document_binov, parent_id: n/a]
2015-05-26 08:13:05,535 6260 INFO odoodb1 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2015 08:13:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2015-05-26 08:13:05,588 6260 ERROR odoodb1 werkzeug: Error on request:
raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `titre` does not exist

Error context:
View `document.form`
[view_id: 873, xml_id: document_binov.document_form, model: document_binov.document_binov, parent_id: n/a]" while parsing /home/binov1/git/odoo/addons/document_binov/templates.xml:29, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_form">
  <field name="name">document.form</field>
  <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <form string="Documents">
     <field name="titre"/> 
    <field name="description"/> 
     <field name="type"/> 
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

Here is the models.py file:

```
 class document_binov(models.Model):
     _name = 'document_binov.document_binov'
     _description = 'visualise les documents'

titre = fields.Char(string='binov')
description = fields.Char(string='binov1')
type = fields.Char(string='binov2')
```

and here is the template.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <openerp>
        <data>

<menuitem name="Documents" id="menu_list_doc" parent="Doc_Bin" sequence="10" />            

    <!-- Form example --> 
     <record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_form">
      <field name="name">document.form</field>
      <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
      <field name="type">form</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <form string="Documents">
         <field name="titre"/> 
        <field name="description"/> 
         <field name="type"/> 
        </form>
      </field>
    </record> 

    <!--Tree view example -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_tree_view">
     <field name="name">document.tree.view</field>
     <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
     <field name="type">tree</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree string="Documents">
          <field name="titre"/>   
          <field name="description"/>
          <field name="type" />
      </tree>
    </field>
    </record>   

     <!-- déclaration d'action -->

     <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_document_work"> 
      <field name="name">Liste des documents</field>
      <field name="res_model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
      <field name="view_type">form</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <!-- <field name="help" type="html"/> --> 
      <field name="document_tree_view" ref="document_form"></field>

    </record>


     <!--déclaration menu -->

    <!-- déclaration de menu niveai 1.1(sans action=non cliquable) -->
    <menuitem id="document_menu" name="Liste des documents" parent="menu_list_doc" action="action_document_work" sequence="10"/> 

        </data>
    </openerp>
```

Comment: You need to adjust your python padding so fields will be part of your class.
If you think everything is ok. Try to restart your server so .py modifications to be taken in consideration, farther, re-update your module.

Answer (score 1):

Python recognizes a block by the number of tabs in each row. in your case, title, description and type are outside the class so they are not declared as attributes.Thats why the system returns that title is not a valid field.

change your python code as

```
class document_binov(models.Model):
     _name = 'document_binov.document_binov'
     _description = 'visualise les documents'

     titre = fields.Char(string='binov')
     description = fields.Char(string='binov1')
     type = fields.Char(string='binov2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `titre` does not exist
```

That means that you have an error in your view.xml. The titre field doesn't exist in your python models field,

this is how to declare fields in your model :

```
_columns={

            'titre': fields.char('titre' , help="titre"),
     }
```

see the odoo documentation for more information about the module creation : [odoo documantation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html)

I hope that help.

Comment: this way of defining fields is right (using _columns). Also, the way they are defined in the question is correct. The difference is the first way used in the old API (openERP 7 and less), and the second in the new API (odoo 8).

Comment: @iouhammi you're wrong, `_columns` is the old api (<=api 7) while the way it was defined in the question is the new api (api 8 and above)